# Suggestion: 2k rep users have to approve or decline proposed edits before instantly editing

Tags: feature-request

I proposed this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19608936 - which corrected some code formatting, added code formatting where it was missing, pulled out the error, corrected some grammar and added a comment regarding grammar in the untouched paragraph.

It received one approval vote before being bulldozed by an edit that came 10 minutes later from a 2k rep user https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50130543/revisions which is in my opinion an inferior edit.

I assume this was not deliberate or malicious of the 2k rep user - on the contrary I believe they're trying to help, but I can't help but feel that when they are automatically rejecting every proposed edit on a post they should first be presented with the edit queue to approve, reject or improve edits manually, to potentially avoid situations where they're not being as helpful as they could be.

Comment: I believe the message is clear "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit". The user didn't even knew that you were editing the post.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Corrected terms, cheers

Comment: @Braiam Yes it is clear, hence my suggestion to change the way it works

Comment: what you are asking about is already there, here you simply faced a case where there is a conflit with another edit like @Braiam said

Comment: Both started editing simultaneously but their edit was sent through before yours and it had to be rejected

Comment: As everyone's said - what you've suggested is how this works already. If a user with full edit privs. tries to edit a post with a  pending suggested edit - they're asked to review the edit and can't directly make an edit of their own without completing the review. However, if they had already decided to make an edit, opened up the editor, had got distracted for a few minutes, came back and finished their edit - their edit would bump your suggested edit out of the queue as has happened here. The editor is unlikely to even know their edit resulted in that happening anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the feature it requests already exists

Comment: @JonClements I see, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

[image: edit (1)]

When a post has a pending edit, attempting to edit it will open the edit review UI and the potential editor needs to accept or dismiss the edit before being able to add their edit.

[image: review UI]

So, nothing to do here, this was merely an edge case with unfortunate timing.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaing. Have added a close vote in that case